# argparse: How to stop interpreting arguments after first argument not starting with '-'?

Tags: python, argparse, command-line-arguments

I am writing a command line tool that executes other commands in a sandbox. 
The basic usage of my tool is:

```
my_tool 'echo "hello"'
```

which executes `echo "hello"`. I would like to be able to write

```
my_tool echo "hello"
```

instead; however, this results in `my_tool: error: unrecognized arguments: hello` because besides the main argument, my tool takes only the boolean option `-n`.

I would like to have `parse_args()` realize that `echo "hello"` is the main argument even if not enclosed by ticks because `echo` starts without a minus, and thus signalizes the beginning of the main argument.

I have tried `parse_known_args()`. However, options of the sandboxed tool get mixed into options of my own tool, e.g.:

```
my_tool echo -n "hello"
```

has the same result as

```
my_tool -n echo "hello"
```

which it shouldn't.

Comment: You might want to checkout sub commands in argparse - if `echo` was a sub command, it would have its own arguments that would only be interpretted if they came after echo: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands  I'm too lazy to fashion this into a proper answer at the moment though.

Answer (score 0):

Add the external tool argument via

```
add_argument('arg',nargs = argparse.REMAINDER)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse-remainder

Comment: `REMAINDER` doesn't work well as the first positional argument.  Better to use it as an optional.